# Triggering function/specific code on the website

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have this code:

```
//Helpful method for getting variables from a url. returns
//null if not found. Decodes any URL encoded vars and also decodes
//any html entities
function getQueryVariable(url,variable) {
  var query = url;
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      var decoded = $('<div/>').html(decodeURIComponent(pair[1])).text();
      return decodeURIComponent(decoded);
    }
  } 
  return null;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //If the doclick parameter is specified, this means
    //the user probably middle-mouse clicked the link.
    //In this case, do the click immediately
    if (window.location.search.indexOf("doclick") != -1) {
        doQueryAndDisplay(getQueryVariable(window.location.search,"linkid"),
                getQueryVariable(window.location.search,"landingpage") != null,
                getQueryVariable(window.location.search,"furl"));
    }

    //When the anchor tag is clicked,
    //we will do an ajax query to see
    //if the asset is gated
    $(".gated-link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Pass the id of the link to the doQuery function, along with the
        //channel id, 
        doQueryAndDisplay(getQueryVariable($(this).attr("href"),"linkid"),
                getQueryVariable($(this).attr("href"),"landingpage") != null,
                getQueryVariable($(this).attr("href"),"furl"));
    });
});
```

It is a part of the website.

How can I find when or on what page, function/feature it will be triggered?

How to trigger it on the page?

The JS code is included in the page in the JS file with script tag.

Can somebody guide on this????

I am debugging this issue and want to pass value to pair[1]

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your asking, but guessing you are looking for what triggers the click event, in your app, and this code is included in many pages?  so the easiest thing to do is search for all the pages which have elements which have a class of `gated-link`, and see if these page include the code above.  The event is a click, so you would click this element to trigger it

Comment: @developer That's what I thought. Do you know also what var decoded = $('<div/>').html(decodeURIComponent(pair[1])).text(); does .... is it replacing </div> with new content???

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: add a break point in the code and then run it, have a look at the contents of the variables in the debugger.  The link above is a ref to information about : decodeURIComponent.

Comment: @developer Thank you for your help. Ahh ... debugger :) Thanks. But I am still confused what $('<div/>') does? It is <div/> not </div>. Would this append html to <div/> tag????

Comment: this `$('<div/>')` creates an unattached element

Comment: This `<div>` is an opening div tag, this `</div>` is a closing div tag, and this  `<div/>` is an empty div section and is equivalent to : <div></div>

Comment: "Would this append html to <div/> tag"  no not unless you attach it in some way to the DOM.  in your code above, it is simply created and used as a mechanism for calling methods

Comment: @developer if i have `<div></div>` in html body and than do `$('<div/>').html("test");` would it update the DOM. Sorry for stupid questions. New and try to also refresh my JS and jQuery knowledge

Comment: no - this is not a selector - it is creating an unattached element.  to select the existing div you would need a selector (ref: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/),  to attach a new element you would append it (ref: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-add-element-to-dom-in-jquery.php).

Comment: Selectors are a subject on their own.  if you want to select all divs in a page you could use `$('div')`,  if the div has an id - you can select that specific div with: `$('div#my-div-id-here')`, if you want to select a group of divs which have a certain class: `$('div.my-class-here')` and to select all element of a certain class: `$('.some-class-here')`

Comment: @developer Thank you for very nice answers